# Iframe Tag not Shown C#

Tags: c#, wordpress, iframe

I am trying to upload video to Wordpress.using following method

```
string expression = videoData.VideoTitle;
string str7 = videoData.VideoTitle;    
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
string s = "security_code=JGZpbGVu&post_content=<iframe width='480' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/XkIdmC8MlkI' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"
                    + "&post_title=" + expression + "&post_category="
                     + "&post_category=" + category + "&category=" + category + "&post_name=" + str7 + "&post_date=" + DATE_STRING;
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
byte[] buffer2 = client.UploadData(uploadPath, "POST", bytes);
string str8 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer2).ToString();
```

it works and everything is posted but the thing in  tags does not get posted i tried some couple of things what turned out is that it had problems with  tag.
when i remove < of iframetag it is displayed but till url and after that everything is gone.
here is the thing which does not performs well

```
"security_code=JGZpbGVu&post_content=test iframe width='480' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/XkIdmC8MlkI' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>&post_title=How to build, upgrade, or repair, your own PC Computer&post_category=&post_category=asd&category=asd&post_name=How to build, upgrade, or repair, your own PC Computer&post_date=2011-05-11 00:00:00"
```

any idea what is wrong?

Comment: can we see what HTML _is_ generated when this is posted?

Comment: @Afnan Like after you make this call then visit your Wordpress powered website you see the new post correct? Copy the HTML of that page (preferably only the section in question) and post it for us to see.

Comment: there goes the Link if i post it here then it would be too bulkey

http://testing.autoprofitbot.com/blogtest/2011/05/10/how-to-be-successful-with-computer-repair/

Comment: have you tried quoting the post_content part? `"security_code=JGZpbGVu&post_content=\"<iframe width='480' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/XkIdmC8MlkI' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>\"..."`

Comment: Wohoho when i quoted here it disappeared

Comment: I meant change your `string s` statement to equal what I posted, run the code and get back to me. Im not sure what `Wohoho when i quoted here it disappeared` means.

Comment: see i tried to quote it that line here but when i clicked quote button on that line see only iframe section dissappears

Comment: that is because it is an HTML tag, surround it in code tags instead (Highlight it and select the **{}** button)

Comment: may be that is what is happning ther

Comment: You still have not done what I told you to do. open your text editor, replace your string, with what I posted, post results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the HTML.

Make sure you reference System.Web, then:

```
string html = @"<iframe width='480' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/XkIdmC8MlkI' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
string s = string.Format("security_code=JGZpbGVu&post_content={0}&post_title={1}&post_category={2}&category={3}&post_name={4}&post_date={5}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(html), expression, category, category, str7, DATE_STRING);
```

Comment: already done `client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: @Afnan: You need to actually URL-encode the body, see updated answer.

Comment: Then I don't have a clue, sorry.